How to select DISTINCT COUNT for only the DAY portion of a date/time column?
I have a table with a column that has date/time markers for some inventory. As you can see in the example data, there are multiple timestamps on a given day.
I want to return the COUNT of how many different days are represented. So in the example below the count would be 3, because I have data from 4/1, 8/4, and 9/18.

I know how to set up a basic COUNT query, but I don't know how to limit the count search to only the day part of the date.
This is what I have so far:
SELECT DISTINCT Count(xyz.RECEIVEDATE) AS CountOfRECEIVEDATE, xyz.ID
FROM xyz
GROUP BY xyz.ID;

I know this won't work, since every row in the example is DISTINCT due to the time stamps. How can I limit it to just the day part?

You'll be more likely to get an answer if you edit the question to include your example data as formatted text. Otherwise, we have to retype everything in order to setup a test sample, and aint no one got time for that. For example, if I could have just copy/pasted your data into dbfiddle I'd probably already have an answer posted. As it is, I'm likely to just move on. Also, we need to know what kind of database you're using and the exact date type of the column.

are 9/1/2023 and 9/1/2024 the same "day"?  or what about 1/1/2023 and 3/1/2023?  I guess the question is at most you'd have 31 counts right?  1-31 since no month has more than 31 days?  Also, what RDBMS and version? different methods for different engines to extract day from a date.

For example: https://dbfiddle.uk/we2eDDl4 in SQL server.  basically count(distinct   Day(date))) but day(date) will vary by RDBMS.

Start by tagging which dbms you are using.  Date functions vary differently for different dbms.

When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.
Why?

It's easier for people to read it.
It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

See here a solution you can live with.
SELECT theDate =CONVERT(DATE , [YourDateTimeMarker])  
    , theCount = COUNT(1) 
FROM YourTable yt
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE , [YourDateTimeMarker])


Please try below solution.
select count(distinct cast(RECEIVEDATE as date)) as count from xyz

Thanks
